# Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open [filename] for writing: No such file or directory

Tags: php, image-processing, file-permissions

I can't figure out why I'm receiving this error when trying to save an image using imagejpeg()

Below is an excerpt from my code where I've eliminated anything extraneous and kept enough to generate the error. The path definitely exists and it has permissions set to 777.

```
$url = "http://website.com";
    $filename = 'imagename';

    $filepath = $url."/Images/accents/generated/".$filename.".jpg";

    $base = imagecreatefromjpeg($url.'/images/'.$filename);
    $imagewidth = imagesx($base);
    $imageheight = imagesy($base);

    $new = imagecreatetruecolor($imagewidth, $imageheight);

    imagecopy($new, $base, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imagewidth, $imageheight);

    imagejpeg($new, $filepath);

    imagedestroy($new);
```

`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely because you're trying to output to a `url` as opposed to a local document...

Your ouput path:

```
http://website.com/Images/accents/generated/imagename.jpg
```

This won't work... The output has to be local, try something like:

```
./Images/accents/generated/imagename.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you times a million. I wouldn't have figured this out and this solved my problem exactly. I am so grateful.